# How to generate a stack trace with in own kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I would like to generate a stack trace report like one generated by kernel oops.

`------------[ cut here ]------------`

`kernel BUG at /home/administrator/project/systech/bsp_tan/linux-.2.6/arch/arm/include/asm/dma-mapping.h:325!`

```
Internal error: Oops - undefined instruction: 0 [#1] PREEMPT
Modules linked in:
CPU: 0    Not tainted  (3.2.6 #67)
PC is at my_func+0x118/0x230
LR is at vprintk+0x3bc/0x440
```

Where it's defined and how I can trigger it with in my module.

`EDIT 1`

How to find the line number where the PC (program counter) was when this bug happened.

`PC is at my_func + 0x118/0x230`

What this means?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `dump_stack()` function ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is in the following files:

```
 lib/bug.c
 kernel/panic.c
```

Comment: thanks,and can we user these files and those functions in our module or driver to trace registers and stack??

Comment: you can call WARN_ON(1) inside your module to get the same report. Just include asm-generic/bug.h